# golangでインポートして関数を使うとundefinedと出る。

Tags: go

```
parent
|-app1: アプリケーション
|
|-common: 共通ライブラリ
```

上のようなディレクトリ構成になっているときに

app1のメイン関数で`common`パッケージをインポートしてその関数を呼び出したのですが`undefined`になってしまいます。なぜでしょうか。

呼び出した`common`の関数は以下のコードの`NewRoutes()`です。
ちなみに依存パッケージは`dep`で`app1`、`common`それぞれで管理しています。

**common/routes.go**

```
package common

import "github.com/labstack/echo"

// Routes is object for routes.
type Routes struct {
    controllers []Controller
}

// NewRoutes is constructor of Routes.
func NewRoutes(controllers ...Controller) *Routes {
    routes := &Routes{}
    for i := range controllers {
        routes.AddController(controllers[i])
    }
    return routes
}

// AddController add a controller.
func (r *Routes) AddController(con Controller) {
    r.controllers = append(r.controllers, con)
}

// ApplyRoutes apply routes of controllers.
func (r *Routes) ApplyRoutes(c echo.Context) {
    for i := range r.controllers {
        r.controllers[i].ApplyRoutes(c)
    }
}
```

**app1/app.go**

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/myuser/myproj/services/common"
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    mw "github.com/labstack/echo/middleware"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.Use(mw.Logger())
    e.Use(mw.Recover())
    e.Use(mw.Gzip())
    // undefined: common.NewRoutes()
    routes := common.NewRoutes()
}
```

Comment: 念のために確認しますが、`go get github.com/myuser/myproj/services/common` は実行済みですね？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。コメントのお陰でなぜこのようなことになっているのかわかりました。`common`の変更をmasterのcommitしていなかったためまだ`NewRoutes`を実装していないバージョンが`app1/vendor`にあったためのようです。現在、`app`も`common`も同じgitレポジトリで管理しているのですが、分けたほうがいいのでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね、、app と common を分けたとしても今回のような「ずれ」が生じる可能性があるかと思います。まぁでも、`import "../common"` などとするのもどうかなぁ、という所ではありますが…

Comment: ありがとう御座います。参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: @StackDestroyer ご存知かと思いますが、相対パスによるimportはなるべく避けた方が良いと思います。 過去の議論の例: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/n9d8RzVnadk/WaSr0Z4F0wsJ